# Pentaho Report Installation Issue For Odoo 8.0 in Ubuntu

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I am in stuck with the installation of the pentaho For  odoo 8.0 in  Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

I have dowloaded the pentaho  report module from the following links for git

[CLICK TO DOWNLOAD FROM THE GIT](https://github.com/WillowIT/Pentaho-reports-for-OpenERP)

And install successfully from my  ODOO 8.0 With Fresh Database

for also refered the below link for installtion  with the different blogs and website some thinks like this

http://www.schenkels.nl/2013/04/creating-a-pentaho-reporting-server-ubuntu-12-04-openerp/

http://blog.instant-erp.com/2013/01/openerp-pentaho-reporting.html and some other

I had done the some of the steps which is mentined in the website or Blogs

like ..

1. Java installation and Apache-Ant Installation and Apache -Ivy Installaed   successfully

2.Tomcat 7 Server installation and its user rights installed successfully

3. I am stuct with this steps for creating the .War file which is useful for deploying the tomcat7 server add apply that command to create the war file some think like this in ubuntu terminal

webtech@webtech-945GCM-S2L:~/Downloads/Pentaho-reports-for-OpenERP-version80/java_server$

ant -lib /usr/local/java war

Give Me Error ::

**> BUILD FAILED

> /home/webtech/Downloads/Pentaho-reports-for-OpenERP-version80/java_server/build-res/subfloor.xml:1160:
>   Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.**

the error tells us the java classes does not understand while creating the war file

How Can I resolve that Error and What are the dependencies is needed to require for this creation of war file for installation ??

Answer (score 1):

If you use the pre-built war file, you should be fine, rather than trying to build it yourself.  All the dependencies are included.

The pre-built war file is mentioned on the git README you have linked to, and it maintains a link to the most recent build.

(The actual download address is currently http://cloud1.willowit.com.au/dist/pentaho-reports-for-openerp.war , but you can always find it via the git repo).